# Rectangle rotation challenge: count the number of (integer) points inside a rotated rectangle on the Cartesian plane

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I encountered this challenge in
[codesignal (The core, question 49)](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/code-arcade/labyrinth-of-nested-loops).
Here is the problem:
A rectangle with sides equal to even integers a and b is drawn on the Cartesian plane. Its center (the intersection point of its diagonals) coincides with the point (0, 0), but the sides of the rectangle are not parallel to the axes; instead, they are forming 45 degree angles with the axes.

How many points with integer coordinates are located inside the given rectangle (including on its sides)?

Example:
[image: Example]

I also have the solution in JS, by another user:

```
function solution(a, b) {
    var pointsA = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(a * a / 2)),
        pointsB = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(b * b / 2));
    return (pointsA * pointsB + Math.floor((pointsA + pointsB) / 2)) * 2 + 1;
}
```

However I cannot understand it. Although the theme of the challenge is nested loop, I still want to understand the math behind this solution. Please explain it to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal of a grid cell has length √2. So the number of oblique rows contained in the rectangle is determined by the integer parts of a/√2 and b/√2. The count of grid nodes is just the product of these numbers of rows, with an adjustment term that accounts for the parities of every other row.

Comment: I get the idea, but it is a bit unclear. Moreover: you need to add it a second time. Why integer pars of a / sqrt(2) * b / sqrt(2) is not enough?